# Control flow not going into control.invoke() delegate winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, invoke

I'm running into an issue where control flow is not going into the Invoke() method of a winforms control.  The situation happens in our application when our application receives notifications that updates a .net data-table.  The only way to "force" it into the invoke is by minimizing and maximizing the application.  This seems to resume the flow back into the Invoke.
Any idea where I should look at?

```
if (InvokeRequired) //this is true
                    {
                        //flow comes here 
                        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                        {//this is not called
                            }
}
```

Comment: A lot of context is missing here. What are you invoking? Something that relies on a specific state? Does it happen if you remove everything and just call `BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { WhateverYouAreDoingHere(); }));`? -- What kind of Control is that? What tasks is it performing? What is instantiating it and how? etc.

Comment: The method inside Invoke or BeginInvoke just removes spinner:
Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                        {//this is not called
                             _grid.Invoke(delegate { spinner.Visible=false});
                            }
This is a multi-threaded application and the issue occurs in a specific scenario where we have incoming notifications updating a .net data-table.  Can it happen that an Invoke called elsewhere doesnt complete(like when its updating the data-table), hence this one is never called?

Comment: As mentioned, you need to put more effort into defining the context of these operations and what is invoking what. -- What is this: `Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => {//this is not called _grid.Invoke(delegate { spinner.Visible=false}); }`: are you calling `Invoke()` on a Control in a MethodInvoker delegate? -- `Invoke()` is synchronous, the execution depends on the current state of the Controls involved. But nobody knows what's happening there...

Comment: If you know this will always need to be invoked, don't bother checking, just invoke it directly. Why are you invoking from the form to the grid to the spinner? Just use the spinner directly: `spinner.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { spinner.Visible = false; });`